# Python VK_API: TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
import rpc
token = 'токен стандалона'
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
user = vk.method('account.getProfileInfo',access_token='токен моего аккаунта')
print(user)
```

В ответ:

```
TypeError: method() got an unexpected keyword argument 'access_token'
```

Я понимаю то, что ошибка возникает из-за того, что в функции метод нет аргумента `access_token`, но куда тогда вставлять `access_token`?
UPD: Документацию читал, ничего подробного не нашел

Comment: Посмотрите в документации/примерах, как передаются параметры эндпоинту через `vk.method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть сразу несколько вариантов. Попробуйте для начала через `vk_api`, я однажды уже столкнулся с этой проблемой, могу разъяснить подробнее в комментариях. Метод `vk_api.VkApi` требует не просто `token`, а `access_token`, возможно, это и есть решение проблемы

```
import vk_api
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(access_token = "ваш токен")
vk = vk_session.get_api()
```

Обнаружил новую схему, которая имеет надежду на выживание. Тут сразу достается новый токен, нужен лишь пароль и логин :

```
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
vk_session.auth()
new_token = vk_session.token['access_token']
```

Comment: Какой TypeError и был, такой к сожалению и остался. vk_api судя по всему последней версии, скачан вчера (TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'access_token')

Comment: Сейчас порылся в своих старых работах, нашел новую схему, не знаю, какие изменения, у меня она работает и по сей день, единственная  проблема будет если в версии vk_api действительно изменили схему авторизации. Ответ уже дополнил.

Comment: Выше приведенный кусок кода работает и не выдает ошибок если вместо токена использовать авторизацию номер/пароль, возможно таким методом работает и мой кусок. UPD: Нет, оно таким образом не работает

Comment: Думаю, тогда проблема решена. Если уж совсем токен нужен, можно создать глобальную переменную new_token, в которую записать токен, полученный с метода vk_session.token. Я решил вашу проблему?

Comment: Я собираюсь использовать свое приложение в одиночку, и мне не имеет значение будет работать оно через токен или через авторизацию, проблема в том, что оба способа оказались нерабочими

Comment: Почти UPD: Токен у меня есть, этот токен надо использовать

Comment: При обращении через браузер пишет, что токен вообще неправильный, он получен с oauth.vk.com

Comment: Попробуйте взять постоянный токен!

Comment: Ваш способ.. работает с другой библиотекой. Мне не критично, какая будет использована, так что спасибо